# In a express/hapi project how to switch to diffrent Mongo DB, based on user login?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a platform, where there is a master DB which holds all the user data, this db is used when user tries to login and after successful login application should fetch data from respective user DB. We are using MongoDB, mongoose driver and epxpress framework. Please guide

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post a minimal example of your code where you want to choose another database. What have you tried/investigated?

Comment: Hello @JeroenHeier . I have not started writing the code yet. This is the use case I have received and unable to think a solution. So I have requested for some idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

You can use [createConnection()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections) to create multiple connections to different databases. 
However, unless you'll only have a handful of users & databases (maybe 10, maybe more), this will very likely not scale very well, since mongoose is not made for this kind of usage. I'd rather advise to either combine the databases into a single one or if you'll have a lot of data or security concerns, create a multi-tenant system hosting an app-instance connected to each database.

Comment: Thanks @BenSower.  May you please provide some reference or idea to create multi-tenant system, as this is what I am trying to build.

Comment: This kinda falls out of the scope of the question, but a common setup would be to have a single gateway to the internet which is connected to a reverse-proxy/loadbalancer (e.g. nginx), and a set of (e.g. docker) containers with databases for each customer behind that.